# (C#/XNA) No matter what, collision never works

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I've been racking my mind on this for days. When updating entities, I check for collision, and if they collide according to the code below, their appropriate motion value is set to 0. Except for some reason, this code doesn't work for checking with collision to its right. If there is a 2 tall wall in front of the entity, it will disregard it. However, it seems to work right if I check below it, but then it will stop completely.

Collision code:

```
    public static bool CollidesRight(Level level, Vector2 position, Vector2 motion, int width, int height)
    {
        Vector2 result = position + motion;
        int x1 = (int)(result.X / (float)Tile.TILE_WIDTH);
        int x2 = (int)((result.X + (float)width) / (float)Tile.TILE_WIDTH) + 1;
        int y1 = (int)(result.Y / (float)Tile.TILE_HEIGHT);
        int y2 = (int)((result.Y + (float)height) / (float)Tile.TILE_HEIGHT);
        AABB resultBB = new AABB(result, width, height);
        for (int i = x1; i < x2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = y1; j < y2; j++)
            {
                if (level.GetTileAt(i, j) != 0 && (Tile.TileList[level.GetTileAt(i, j)].IsSolid() || Tile.TileList[level.GetTileAt(i, j)].HasSolidTop()))
                {
                    AABB tile = new AABB(new Vector2(i * 64f, j * 64f), 64, 64);
                    Console.WriteLine(tile);
                    return resultBB.Intersects(tile);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Here's my entity's updating code:

```
    public virtual void Tick()
    {
        lastMotion = motion;
        lastPosition = position;
        if (Collision.CollidesBottom(level, position, motion, width, height))
        {
            onGround = true;
        }
        else if(!Collision.CollidesBottom(level, position, motion, width, height))
        {
            onGround = false;
        }

        if (onGround && !isJumping)
        {
            motion.Y = 0f;
            fallDistance = 0;
        }
        else if(!onGround)
        {
            fallDistance++;
            motion.Y += gravity * (fallDistance * 0.005f);
        }

        if (isJumping)
        {
            timeJumping++;
            if (timeJumping > 32)
            {
                timeJumping = 0;
                isJumping = false;
            }
            else
            {
                motion.Y = -2.25f;
            }
        }

        position.Y += motion.Y;

        if (motion.X != 0)
        {
            if (motion.X < 0)
            {
                motion.X += friction;
            }
            if (motion.X > 0)
            {
                motion.X -= friction;
            }
        }

        if ((motion.X > 0 && Collision.CollidesRight(level, position, motion, width, height)) || (motion.X < 0 && Collision.CollidesLeft(level, position, motion, width, height)))
        {
            motion.X = 0f;
        }

        position.X += motion.X;



        //MoveEntity(motion);
    }
```

Comment: So you're saying, `Collision.CollidesBottom` works as intended but `Collision.CollidesRight` (or `CollidesLeft`) does not?

Comment: I would also like to know more about `AABB`; is that something you made yourself? If so, please post the implementation. Seeing what `Level.GetTileAt(int, int)` does would be interesting as well. Because right now it looks to me that, as soon as you find **any** tile that is _solid_ or has a _hard top_, you return `resultBB.Intersects(tile)`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6d8YAGpb here's the AABB, http://pastebin.com/8skaNAc6 and Level.GetTileAt(int x, int y). Tiles have an IsSolid() and HasSolidTop() declaration, and grass and air tiles are solid and nonsolid respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 options for you.

First, **Edit - nevermind about this one, i misread your code** I think you should add your X motion before doing the collision check, since the collision check uses it to work.  If you don't want to add it to the actual player motion, at least pass the potential motion into the function.  That alone might fix everything.  But there's another problem.

Second, **and I'm pretty sure it's this one**, I suspect that your position.Y is frequently truncated to an Int when your OnGround bool is set. Which means it's minimum will be a whole unit and the next unit up will be a whole unit. And in your AABB code from pastebin:

```
if (bb.max.Y <= min.Y || bb.min.Y >= max.Y)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

This code will return false even if the X-coordinate related code detects a collision.  You should modify the logic in here so that the function returns true if there is a collision, **instead of returning false on two independent checks**.

Third, assuming your width is 1 unit and your tiles are also 1 unit wide, with a block at x=2 and position.x = 0.5, and a very small xMotion (or one that hasn't been added in yet, see answer 1):

(occupying some of block 0 and some of block 1, like so)

```
[.][ ][X]
```

You want to stop when you hit x = 1, because then you'll be up against your obstruction.  But:

x1 = (int)(0.5) = 0 
x2 = (int)(0.5 + 1) + 1 = 2

so your loop:

```
for (int i = x1; i < x2; i++)
```

checks block 0 (which is empty, then checks block 1 (which is empty) and then stops (because  i == x2) and never checks block 2.  So the block you care about never gets its collision check.  I think if you change it to

```
for (int i = x1; i <= x2; i++)
```

then everything will work better at detecting an oncoming collision.  You should probably do something similar for your future CollidesTop function.

P.S.  Try these answers one at a time, of course.  :)